# Как структурировать(организовать по порядку) текст и фотографии на сайте?

Tags: html, css

Необходимо, чтобы текст хедера был выше фотографий body.

Как мне это организовать?

HTML:

```
    <header>
    <div>
        <p>
            <h1>На какой канал вы хотите перейти?</h1>
        </p>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
    <img src="images/thumb3" alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу." class="round">
    <p>
        <h3>thumb3</h3>
    </p>
    <img src="images/thumb2.jpg" alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу." class="round">
    <p>
        <h3>thumb2</h3>
    </p>
    <img src="images/thumb3.jpg" alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу." class="round">
    <p>
        <h3>thumb3</h3>
    </p>
    <img src="images/thumb4.jpg" alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу." class="round">
    <p>
        <h3>thumb4</h3>
    </p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap');
    body {
        box-sizing: content-box;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: wheat;
    }
    
    h1 {
        color: black;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 32pt;
    }
    
    h3 {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16pt;
    }
    
    .round {
        border-radius: 100px;
        /* Радиус скругления */
        border: 3px solid green;
        /* Параметры рамки */
        box-shadow: 0 0 7px #666;
        /* Параметры тени */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: А как у Вас существует header снаружи body?

Comment: Переместил хедер внутрь боди, ничего не изменилось

Comment: По структуре html документа весь "контент" находится в body (тело документа) и  все семантические теги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум, я бы сделал так

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap');

    body {
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: content-box;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: wheat;
    }

    h1 {
      color: black;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 32pt;
    }

    h3 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16pt;
    }

    .block {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;

    }

    .item {
      flex-basis: 40%;
    }

    .round {
      border-radius: 100px;
      /* Радиус скругления */
      border: 3px solid green;
      /* Параметры рамки */
      box-shadow: 0 0 7px #666;
      /* Параметры тени */
    }
  </style>
  <header>
    <div>
      <p>
      <h1>На какой канал вы хотите перейти?</h1>
      </p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/thumb3"
        alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу."
        class="round">
      <p>
      <h3>thumb3</h3>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.item -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/thumb2.jpg"
        alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу."
        class="round">
      <p>
      <h3>thumb2</h3>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.item -->
    <div class="item"><img src="images/thumb3.jpg"
        alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу."
        class="round">
      <p>
      <h3>thumb3</h3>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.item -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/thumb4.jpg"
        alt="Видимо, у вас не прогрузилась картинка. Перезагрузите страницу или нажмите на надписи снизу."
        class="round">
      <p>
      <h3>thumb4</h3>
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.item -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.block -->
```

Comment: Как поместить это всё в центр сайта?

Comment: как должно идти? все в столбик? все в строчку ?

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли. Получилось так, как надо.